# vue computed property getter error => [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'periodNum' of undefined"

Tags: vue.js

```
    data() {
        return {
            unitPrice: 0.00,
            periodNum: 0,
             //totalPrice
        }
    },
    computed:{
        totalPrice: ()=>{
            return this.periodNum * this.unitPrice;
        }
    },
methods:{... change periodNum and unitPrice functions here}
```

I followed vue doc to do this: compute totalPrice when periodNum and unitPrice are changed, however I got the error in question title, at the 'return' line

Answer (score 2):

Don't use arrow functions. Use normal `function` or shorthand like this:

```
computed: {
    totalPrice() {
        return this.periodNum * this.unitPrice;
    }
}
```